# Using Jensen inequality to show $|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i|\le \ldots \le c\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}$

Tags: inequality

My goal is to have a chain of inequalities so that $|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i|\le \ldots \le c\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}$

$|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i|\le\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_ix_i|=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{(a_ix_i)^2}\le\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_ix_i)^2}\le\sqrt{\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}a_i^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}=\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}|a_i|\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Jensen inequality means for a convex function, $f$, we have

$$f(E(X)) \le E(f(X))$$

square root is a concave function.

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{(a_ix_i)^2}}{n} \le \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(a_ix_i)^2}{n}}$$

Hence we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{(a_ix_i)^2}\le \sqrt{n}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(a_ix_i)^2}$$

To see that $\sqrt{n}$ can't be omitted, let $a_i=1, n=2, x_1=3, x_2=4$.

Without $\sqrt{n}$, we have $$3+4 \le \sqrt{3^2+4^2}$$ which is not true.

Edit:

By Cauchy-Schwarz,

$$|\langle a, x \rangle | \le \|a\|_2 \|x\|_2$$

Comment: Hmm okay, I need it for part b) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2999496/calculating-operator-norm-ax

to show $|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i|\le \ldots \le c\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}$ but I don't know what to do. Maybe it's C-S inequality or something completely different I don't know

Comment: You mean $c$ can't depend on $n$? most of your working is correct.

Comment: CS is a good idea too.

Comment: The $c$ should be some norm of $A$ I guess, so maybe $c=\|A\|_\infty$ or $c=\|A\|_2$, something like this but I can't do it

Comment: why do you divide by 'n' in the second line?

Comment: I was evaluating the expectation.